# I have a C# WPF application that needs to be packaged. Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, installation, packaging

so I have an application that I have created in Visual Studio 2010 and I want to know how I can package it so a user can install it on their machine.  I'm sure I will have to do some scripting as well as call cmd prompts.  Basically I want to get it to the point where there is an installer for the application that my group has built.

Any suggestions or tutorials you recommend??  Its for a school project and it would really be helpful if someone could help me get this off the ground.  Its the last thing my group needs to do.

Thanks!

Joe Ristaino

Answer (score 2):

Use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the MSI installer setup project in Visual studio. It's very simple.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx

I wouldn't use click once...

Ok here's a newer article

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has it's own installer projects, you could check those out. I personally use them for any projects I make at my company. If you use the wizard, you'll have it done in no time.

In your solution,

1. `right click` your solution name in the Solution Explorer.
2. `Add` -> `New Project`.
3. For the type, goto `Other Project Types` -> `Setup And Deployment` -> `Visual Studio Installer`

Choose the setup wizard, it's pretty easy. Primary output means what's is installed to the program folder. Follow the wizard and most of the work will be done. There will only be optional tweaking left to do.

Comment: +1 don't know why you were downvoted.  My guess is someone with an aversion to the term "Wizard" being used in a programing context.

Comment: @smoore: Thanks. I know who downvoted me and why. Suffices to say, the downvote was over comments on another poster's answer. I flagged some material in the argument and the whole thing was subsequently removed. The downvote that was placed during the argument, however, lingered.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html). It's got quite a bit of a learning curve, but it's totally powerful.

It's expected to be included in the next version of Visual Studio (it didn't quite make it into VS2010).